# Converting Java main to Android Extend activity

Tags: java, android, function, type-conversion

Currently i am trying to convert the piece of Java coding into Android studio.
Here is the original code

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ModbusClient modbusClient = new ModbusClient("192.168.1.106",502);
        try
        {
            modbusClient.Connect();
            modbusClient.WriteSingleCoil(0, true);
            modbusClient.WriteSingleRegister(0, 1234);
            modbusClient.ConvertFloatToTwoRegisters((float) 123.56));

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {       
        }   
}
```

---

And here is the edited version in Android Studio:

```
public class medusaTest extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mb);
        Button b = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v)  {
                ModbusClient modbusClient = new ModbusClient("192.168.1.106",502);
                try
                {
                    modbusClient.Connect();
                    modbusClient.WriteSingleCoil(0, true);
                    modbusClient.WriteSingleRegister(0, 1234);
                    modbusClient.WriteMultipleRegisters(11, ModbusClient.ConvertFloatToTwoRegisters((float) 123.56));
                    //System.out.println(modbusClient.ReadCoils(0, 1)[0]);
                    //System.out.println(modbusClient.ReadHoldingRegisters(0, 1)[0]);
                    //System.out.println(ModbusClient.ConvertRegistersToFloat(modbusClient.ReadHoldingRegisters(11, 2)));
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                }
            }
        });

    }
    }
```

the problem is, whenever i tried to run it on android, it keep stopping the application. Please give me advice and help me to run this code in Android. Thank you

Comment: can you show us the LogCat ?

Comment: have you added the imports in both files?

Comment: @ACV yeah i added.

Comment: nothing worse than a `try` with empty `catch`, add this to your catch and see what exception is logged in logcat `e.printStackTrace();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the answer for my question. The solution

add the code after Setcontentview(R.Layout.main_activity) in public class

The code:

```
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }
```

My problem has been solved. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

make sure you add the internet permission to your `manifest.xml` file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: I will add this one now.